# Java BufferedReader Returning Array Twice?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, bufferedreader

I've got the java method below that prints the authorArray ArrayList twice, but the second time it's printed, the entire array is printed twice? There's probably something really obvious wrong with it, but I've been looking at it for so long now that I can't see the problem. The method is part of a class, but all the relevant code is shown below.

Thanks in advance!

```js
 
public File[] getAuthors() throws IOException {
    String authorName = null;
    ArrayList<String> authorArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\Jane\\workspace\\TextMining\\bin"); //Create new file with directory of texts
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); //Create a list that will store all file directories
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile() && listOfFiles[i].getName().endsWith(".txt")) { //If the current item is a file...
            try (BufferedReader authorReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(listOfFiles[i].getName()))) { //Create a buffered reader for each text file
                authorName = authorReader.readLine();
                authorArray.add(authorName); //Store the author name in an arraylist
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(authorArray);
    return listOfFiles;
}
```

And here's the output:

```js
[Sir Arthur Conan Doyle, Sir Arthur Conan Doyle, Darren Brown , Dan Brown, J.K. Rowling, J.K. Rowling, Michael Crichton , Michael Crichton]
[Sir Arthur Conan Doyle, Sir Arthur Conan Doyle, Darren Brown , Dan Brown, J.K. Rowling, J.K. Rowling, Michael Crichton , Michael Crichton, Sir Arthur Conan Doyle, Sir Arthur Conan Doyle, Darren Brown , Dan Brown, J.K. Rowling, J.K. Rowling, Michael Crichton , Michael Crichton]
```

Comment: there is only one `print` line, the output shows 2, where is the second one?

Comment: show the whole code

Comment: How many files are in that folder?

Comment: That's the only print command in the code, which I found to be a little strange. And there's 10 text files at the minute, more as a worst-case-scenario than anything else